# if statement python for every two values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is example code:

```
List1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['1', '2', '3']]
range_value = len(List1) * 2
for x in range(0, range_value):
   if x == 0 or x == 1:

       for y in List1[0]:
           print y
           print x
   if x == 2 or x == 3:
       for y in List1[1]:
           print y
           print x

   if x == 4 or x == 5:
       for y in List1[2]:
            print y
            print x
```

This code is looks  manual steps defining if statement.

In case I have big values like 100 or 1000 of sub lists.

I have to write 100's or 1000's of if statement,

if x value is 0 and 1 print List1[0] values and if x value is 2 and 3  print List1[1], if x value is 4 and 5 print List1[2] .

print x value also like below

print  x is 0 and print y of  List1[0], print  x is 1 and print y of  List1[0], print x is 2 and print y of List1[1], print x is 3 and print y of List2[1] and so on

Help me here

Comment: `List1[int(x / 2)]` or maybe `List1[x >> 1]`

Answer (score 1):

Since your indices are grouped by two's you can do the following such that the same operation will occur twice.

```
List1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['1', '2', '3']]

for x in xrange(len(List1) * 2):
    print x
    for y in List1[x//2]: print y
```

---

## In Python 3

Since your indices are grouped by two's you can do the following such that the same operation will occur twice.

```
List1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['1', '2', '3']]

for x in range(len(List1) * 2):
    print(x)
    for y in List1[x//2]: print(y)
```

Using list comprehensions you can also do

```
List1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['1', '2', '3']]

[print(y) for x in range(len(List1) * 2) for y in List1[x//2]]
```

Comment: The question is tagged python 2

Comment: Hi JanKnows, I need to print x value also just edited question

Comment: At the start of each sequence?

Comment: print  x is 0 and print y of  List1[0], print  x is 1 and print y of  List1[0], print x is 2 and print y of List1[1], print x is 3 and print y of List2[1] and so on

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use `if` statments. You can make your code mode dynamic by this way:

```
for x in List1:            # Iterate over the list of lists
    for _ in range(2):     # Do the process below two times like you want
        for y in x:        # Iterate over each item of the sublist
            print(y)       # Print the item
```

Another idea could be double the iterations of the first loop, and then use a floor division:

```
for x in range(len(List1) * 2):
    for y in List1[x//2]:      # Floor division would turn 0//2 > 0, 1//2 > 0, 2//2 > 1, 3//2 > 1, 4//2 > 1... efectively doubling the loop
        print(y)
```

Note that my code is in python 3. In order to translate to python 2 I think you have to delete brakets of `print` and change `range` to `xrange` (better perfomance).

Also, if you really want to use `if` statement, I would recomend use `elif` instead of `if` in the lines below the first one, that will make you code a bit faster since the another conditionals won't be checked if someone above of them is true.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your inner for loop runs based on value of x/2:
This works:

```
def runMethod(x,List1):
    if x %2 == 0:
        for y in List1[int(x/2)]:
            print y
            print x




List1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['1', '2', '3']]
range_value = len(List1) * 2
for x in range(0, range_value):
    runMethod(x,List1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use a variable to replace the first and second arguments. Then increase it incrementally. 
For example,

```
for x in range(0, range_value):
    if x == first_variable or x == second_variable:
        for y in List[first_variable]:
            print(y)
    first_variable += 2
    second_variable += 2
```